# Selecting one output when regex matches more than once

Tags: awk

Given an input file containing multiple rows of my target

```
...
100 100 100 100
Expression: out1
200 200 200 200
300 300 300 300
Expression: out2
400 400 400 400
500 500 500 500
Expression: out3
...
```

If I do

```
awk '/Expression:/ {printf " %f ",$2 } ' $file
```

I get multiple outputs

```
 out1 out2 out3
```

How could I choose only one of the output based on the position they are found on the file, for instance `out3`?

Comment: whether in same row 3 columns are there ?

Comment: @Manolete: Kindly post some sample Input_file and expected sample output.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Done

Comment: @Manolete: Also if you could add expected output too, as I think still it is not 100% clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For - If n number of rows found for the regex matched, then how to select last one ?**

```
awk '/Expression:/ { last_found = $2 }END{print last_found }' file
```

**Display nth match for the given regex**

```
awk '/Expression:/ { if(++i==3){ print $2; exit } }' file
```

**Input**

```
akshay@db-3325:~$ cat f
...
100 100 100 100
Expression: out1
200 200 200 200
300 300 300 300
Expression: out2
400 400 400 400
500 500 500 500
Expression: out3
...
```

**Output**

```
# for 3rd one
akshay@db-3325:~$ awk '/Expression:/ { if(++i==3){ print $2; exit } }' f
out3

# For 2nd one
akshay@db-3325:~$ awk '/Expression:/ { if(++i==2){ print $2; exit } }' f
out2

# For last one
akshay@db-3325:~$ awk '/Expression:/ { last_found = $2 }END{print last_found }' f
out3
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply count the occurrences and print the last value once the counter has reached the threshold:

```
awk '/Expression/{c+=1;s=$2};c==3{print s}'
```